# Wrong mapping swagger ui

Tags: spring, swagger, springfox

I tried to view the api documentation generated by swagger with springfox on the link `localhost:8081/swagger-ui.html` but I received the error `configuration/ui Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`.

I checked and I found the correct url for `configuration/ui` is `swagger-resources/configuration/ui`.

Dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

How I can resolv this bad mapping?

Comment: what is the version of swagger -ui used ?

Comment: Swagger 2. I put dependencies in post.

Comment: can you change both to 2.7.0 and try ?

Comment: Please change both

Comment: Apparently work, thanks. But who I can change the version of design for example I want to have similary with http://petstore.swagger.io/?_ga=2.7782970.968212434.1505119152-930472596.1505119152#/

Comment: I think it is due to version mismatch with respect to ui and spring fox and it has different endpoint mappings. if you look into the logs you will find more about the endpoints mapped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change both the swagger version to 2.7.0

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```